# How to fix couch covering material

Tags: repair

This may sound like a stupid question but I only have this couch for a few years.

It has a type of synthetic skin, maybe nappa and it's getting all damaged, and splitting in some places.

Here is what is what's happening

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the skin to get out? Is there a good suggestion to fix it?

Maybe I can buy a material that is similar and myself do some patches.

Comment: Your material ( which is on the outside )  is not "getting out" is being damaged, scratched  and or splitting.

Comment: the damage on left side of the vertical line is scratches .... you can see that something was dragged across the material ... almost looks like damage made by a cat